# How Jetty9 disabled own Webapp config and use new

Tags: java, xml, jetty, jetty-9

The Jetty9 start.ini different with Jetty8.
In Jetty8, I can comment all xml quote, then can disabled the own xml setting, like this

```
#etc/jetty-jmx.xml
#etc/jetty.xml
#etc/jetty-annotations.xml
#etc/jetty-ssl.xml
#etc/jetty-requestlog.xml
#etc/jetty-deploy.xml
#etc/jetty-overlay.xml
#etc/jetty-webapps.xml
#etc/jetty-contexts.xml
#etc/jetty-testrealm.xml
etc/jetty-jenkins.xml
```

but in jetty9, I can't find this in start.ini.
I create new setting by http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/serving-webapp-from-particular-port.html and I want to disabled jetty9 own xml setting.

```
--module=websocket
--module=ext
--module=resources
--module=jsp
jsp-impl=apache
--module=jstl
--module=http
jetty.port=8080
http.timeout=30000
etc/ajetty-jenkins.xml
```

use above config, it can load ajetty-jenkins.xml, but own webapp start so.How disabled it.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What does `etc/jetty-jenkins.xml` do? (can you paste it in your question)